# Email link to launch executable. Will my email get blocked as spam or dangerous?

Tags: email, security, virus-scanning

Just wondering if anyone has experience in sending an email with a link in it to launch an executable.

We have clients that require a license key of sorts to be emailed to them, I had an idea to send a link that would launch at executable on the local system and import the license automatically, but I'm assuming this would be blocked by virus protection or spam blockers. Am I right in assuming this?

I am also up for other suggestions on how to import a long string of data in to a database easily without much user interaction.

Thanks :)

Comment: This is the definition of a virus that will get you blacklisted by every AV maker that sees it, as well as most companies that have any kind of security established. Users are educated (beaten over the head, really) to teach them **not** to click on links in emails, and you want to make it worse by linking to an executable? Even if your purpose is legit, you're asking users to do exactly what every IT admin is trying to teach them not to do.

Comment: Yeah mate, just an idea.

Comment: The idea is horrible.

Comment: Ok, Thanks mate.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes it does but in most cases the strategy is not governed by the developer.

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara: The post says *I had an idea*. Even if it wasn't the developer's choice, I'd still make the point to whoever was making that choice that it's a horrible, dangerous and (from a business sense, as well as potentially others) an extremely risky idea. Every business I've worked at, every client I've had, and every knowledgeable user I know would ban this software from our network, offices and desktop, and word of that would spread pretty fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a link to an executable does not seem like a good idea for me since the user have to download an application manually and execute it.

Probably you can make the licensing logic a part of core application and launch the application using a custom URI scheme. As an example your URL looks like abc://myurl.com?parameters. When the user clicks on it your application gets launched with necessary parameters. The application knows how to proceed with the licensing process from that point onward.